# PostgreSQL module - How to map an array of parameters into the function?

Tags: c, postgresql, gcc

Am trying to convert a little bit of C test code into a PostgreSQL v1 module

Code originally designed as a simple command line, which takes a variable number - an array - of text arguments; from 3 to 7

the original code's declarations are commented; I'm now trying to convert that into a PG shared object *function*. All of the arguments to the function will be text strings (base command, options, etc.)

how can I declare/pass the array into the function?

```
    PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(embed_0);

Datum
embed_0(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)

// THIS was the declaration when it was a C executable:
// int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
// don't think mapping argc to a PG type is needed here, right?
// (argc is not a parameter?)
int     *argc; // = PG_GETARG_INT32(0);
char    argv[] = PG_GETARG_TEXT_P(0);

int i;
Object *pName, *pCall, *pPart1, *pPart2, *pArgs, *pValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a variable number of arguments you need to either:

- Declare it [`VARIADIC`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html);
- Create *n* different signatures for the function with different numbers of arguments;  or
- In `C` create only the most general form, the 7-argument variety, and then create SQL function wrappers for the fewer-arguments cases that call the most general form.

If you really only need 3,4,5,6, and 7-argument versions I'd do something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION embed0(text,text,text,text,text,text,text) RETURNS text
LANGUAGE 'C' AS 'embed0','embed0';

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION embed0(text,text,text) RETURNS text AS $$
SELECT embed0($1,$2,$2,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
$$ LANGUAGE 'SQL';

// ... etc
```

If 7 args was just an arbitrary upper bound and you can actually take any number of arguments you should instead just write:

```
CREATE FUNCTION embed0(text,text,text,VARIADIC text) RETURNS text
LANGUAGE 'C' AS 'embed0','embed0';
```

and handle the variable arguments in your `C` function. See the PostgreSQL source code for the `concat` function for how. Its implementation is `text_concat` in `src/backend/utils/adt/varlena.c` on line 3842 in current git head; your line number will differ. Most of the work is done in `concat_internal`.

Another example is the `format` function, with C implementation `text_format` (via lookup in `pg_proc.h`), located in `varlena.c` (according to `git grep '^text_format'`; Pg coding style rules specify that the function name must begin on the hard left of the line), line 3953 in current git. While a more complicated function it might be better as an example for you because it does all the work in one place rather than splitting out for a helper function call. It's declared in `pg_proc.h` but if it were declared in SQL it'd look something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION format(text, VARIADIC text) RETURNS text AS 'internal','text_format';
```

There you'll see that `VARIADIC` arguments are accessed like any other from `C`, using the `PG_GETARG_...(argno)` macros. The `PG_NARGS()` macro reports the number of arguments passed. `VARIADIC` arguments may be null so you have to use `PG_ARGISNULL(argno)` and handle the case of a null argument.

So: I'd write it as a `VARIADIC` function using `PG_NARGS`, `PG_GETARG_TEXT_P`, `PG_ARGISNULL`. Because Pg's `VARIADIC` functions cannot be called implicitly with zero variadic arguments, I'd write a wrapper for the 3-argument case that does:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION embed_0(text,text,text) RETURNS text AS $$
SELECT embed_0($1,$2,$2, VARIADIC ARRAY[]::text[]);
$$ LANGUAGE 'SQL';
```

, passing an empty array as the variadic parameter. That way you can call it with 3 args too.

**BTW, when coding be aware that the string in a Pg `text` is not null terminated, unlike those passed to `main()`. You must use the lengths PostgreSQL provides.**. See `src/include/fmgr.h`, the tutorial, and the text handling in the functions in the source code. Don't use `strlen`, `strcat`, `strcpy`, etc because they expect null-terminated strings.